# Angular2: Very strange/sudden issue when using ngSubmit to pass a String to a function

Tags: html, angular

I am busy with a Angular2 web app and running into a very strange issue...  I have a model driven form that uses `ngSubmit` to pass a barcode value to a `findProduct()` function.  Everything worked fine about an hour ago, but now when I click the Scan button the page reloads and I don't get any output in the google dev tools console.  I've tried to console.log the barcode in the `findProduct()` function but still no output in the console, the page just reloads whenever the button is clicked.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong/How I can debug this kind of issue?

my code:

**html template:**

```
<form role="form" [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="findProduct(productForm.value.barcode)">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter Barcode" [formControl]="productForm.controls['barcode']">
    <small [hidden]="productForm.controls['barcode'].valid || (productForm.controls['barcode'].pristine && !productForm.submitted)">barcode required</small>
    <button class="btn btn-submit pull-right" [disabled]="!productForm.valid">Scan</button>
</form>
```

**controller:**

```
findProduct(barcode: string) {
   console.log(barcode);
   this.product.GoodsReceivedID = this.GRNIDKey;      
   this.restService.findCaptureItem(this.GRNIDKey, barcode)
      .subscribe(
      (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.product = res;
      },
      (res) => {
          console.log(res);   
      });
}
```

**Service:**

```
findCaptureItem(GRNIDKey: string, barcode: string) : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.API_URL + 'PurchaseOrder/FindPurchaseOrderItem/' + GRNIDKey + '/' + barcode)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error'));
  }
```

Comment: Deleted my answer. I was reading the question a bit poorly. Didn't realize it worked "before". Now when I read your question again with my brain activated, I saw that :P

Comment: No worries:0 Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue occurred on the line:

```
   this.product.GoodsReceivedID = this.GRNIDKey;
```

The issue was that this.product has been declared but not yet initialized...  I think it's really strange that there was no Warning/Error in either the Google developer console or angular-cli (Windows command prompt)...